# How can I minimize queries when serving JSON through a Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder, rails-api

I'm preparing an API in rails to serve an AngularJS app. This app will provide a dashboard for managing people in a database, so the main page for an individual person is pulling in a lot of information. Here's the Jbuilder file I'm using to format the information as JSON:

```
json.extract! @person, :id, :employee_id, :display_name
json.appointments @person.appointments, :id, :jobcode, :title
json.flags @person.flags, :id, :name
json.source_relationships @person.source_relationships, :id, :source_id, :target_id, :relationship_type_id
json.target_relationships @person.target_relationships, :id, :source_id, :target_id, :relationship_type_id
```

The JSON returned looks like this (from `/api/v1/people/1685.json`):

```
{
  "id":1685,
  "employee_id":"9995999",
  "display_name":"John Doe",
  "appointments": [
    {"id":353,"jobcode":"TE556","title":"Developer"}
  ],
  "flags":[
    {"id":5,"name":"Unclassified"},
    {"id":7,"name":"Full Time"}
  ],
  "source_relationships":[
    {"id":19,"source_id":1685,"target_id":1648,"relationship_type_id":9},
    {"id":21,"source_id":1685,"target_id":1606,"relationship_type_id":9}
  ],
  "target_relationships":[
    {"id":1,"source_id":1648,"target_id":1685,"relationship_type_id":10}
  ]
}
```

And the console shows these queries:

```
Person Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `people`.* FROM `people`  WHERE `people`.`id` = 1685 LIMIT 1
Appointment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `appointments`.* FROM `appointments`  WHERE `appointments`.`person_id` = 1685
Flag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `flags`.* FROM `flags` 
    INNER JOIN `flags_people` ON `flags`.`id` = `flags_people`.`flag_id` WHERE `flags_people`.`person_id` = 1685
Relationship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `relationships`.* FROM `relationships`  WHERE `relationships`.`source_id` = 1685
Relationship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `relationships`.* FROM `relationships`  WHERE `relationships`.`target_id` = 1685
```

I like the way the JSON is formatted, but the fact that it has to run 5 separate queries seems inefficient. I tried adding `joins()` or `includes()` methods to active record query, which is currently just: `@person = Person.find(params[:id])`, but that didn't seem to be what I wanted. How can I cleanly minimize the number of queries while still returning JSON in a similar format?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't seem to be what I wanted?". You clearly want some kind of eager loading. What does `Person.joins(:flags, :appointments, :source_relationships, :target_relationships).find(params[:id])` (or whatever it would be since you didn't show your models) differ from what you want?

Comment: optimization and json format have nothing to do with each other

Comment: @ptd - It seems like the query you suggested is joining all the required tables to the `people` table, but the additional queries (`SELECT * FROM appointments`, `SELECT * FROM flags`, etc.) are still being run. That's why I thought `joins()` wasn't the method I was looking for. I ran into the same situation with `includes()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I was looking for is `eager_load`. Not sure how I haven't come across it in the past, but it combined all the table queries into one using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
@person = Person.eager_load(:flags, :appointments,
:source_relationships, :target_relationships).find(params[:id])
```

Results in this single query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `people`.`id` FROM `people` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `flags_people` ON `flags_people`.`person_id` = `people`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `flags` ON `flags`.`id` = `flags_people`.`flag_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `appointments` ON `appointments`.`person_id` = `people`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relationships` ON `relationships`.`source_id` = `people`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `relationships` `target_relationships_people` ON `target_relationships_people`.`target_id` = `people`.`id` 
WHERE `people`.`id` = 1685 LIMIT 1
```

Found the explanation on [this blog post from Arkency](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)